# Proof verification: Characterising the domain of a self-adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, operator-theory, spectral-theory, self-adjoint-operators

Consider a separable, complex Hilbert space $H$ and a self-adjoint operator $A: D(A) \longrightarrow H$, where $D(A)$ is a dense subspace. Assume that $A$ admits an orthonormal basis $\{\varphi_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ as eigenvectors: $A \varphi_n =a_n\varphi_n$.  I want to prove the following:

$$x\in \mathcal D(A) \iff (a_n \langle \varphi_n,x\rangle)_{n\in \mathbb N} \in \ell^2\quad . $$

**Proof attempt.** If $x\in D(A)$, then we can expand $Ax \in H$ in the eigenbasis of $A$, which yields that $$Ax=\sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N} \langle \varphi_n,Ax\rangle \varphi_n = \sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N} a_n \langle \varphi_n,x\rangle \varphi_n \quad .$$ But as $Ax\in H$, we have that $(a_n \langle \varphi_n,x\rangle)_{n\in \mathbb N} \in \ell^2$.

Conversely, if $(a_n \langle \varphi_n,x\rangle)_{n\in \mathbb N} \in \ell^2$ holds for some $x\in H$, then there exists a unique $y\in H$ such that

$$ y= \sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N}  a_n \langle \varphi_n,x\rangle \varphi_n \quad .$$

Expanding $y$ in the eigenbasis of $A$, on the other hand, gives
$$y= \sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N}  \langle \varphi_n,y\rangle \varphi_n \quad ,   $$

which due to the uniqueness of the expansion coefficients yields

$$\forall n\in \mathbb N: a_n \langle x,\varphi_n\rangle  = \langle x,A\varphi_n\rangle= \langle y,\varphi_n\rangle \quad .   $$

Recalling that $$D(A^*):=\left\{ x\in H | \exists y\in H: \forall \varphi \in D(A): \langle x,A\varphi\rangle = \langle y,\varphi\rangle\right\} $$ and, as $A$ is self-adjoint, $A=A^*$ and $D(A)=D(A^*)$, it thus suffices to show that $x \in D(A^*)$ in the sense above. Then also $A^*x =Ax=y$.

To do so, expand $\varphi\in D(A)$ in the eigenbasis of $A$, which shows that
$$\langle y,\varphi\rangle = \sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N} \langle y,\varphi_n\rangle \langle \varphi_n,\varphi \rangle =\sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N} a_n \langle x,\varphi_n\rangle\langle \varphi_n,\varphi\rangle =\sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N}  \langle x,A\varphi_n\rangle\langle \varphi_n,\varphi\rangle = \langle x,A\varphi\rangle \quad , $$

for all $\varphi \in D(A)$. Thus $x\in D(A^*)=D(A)$, concluding the proof.

We've used the continuity of the inner product, the self-adjointness (and thus symmetry) of $A$ as well as (variants of) the Riesz-Fischer theorem multiple times.

---

Is this proof correct? If so, can it be improved?

Comment: I don't understand the very last equality.  Can you clarify?  The rest looks ok.

Comment: @JohnDoe Basically we have that $ \displaystyle A\varphi=\sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N} \langle \varphi_n,A\varphi\rangle \varphi_n = \sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N} \langle \varphi_n,\varphi\rangle  a_n \varphi_n = \sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N} \langle \varphi_n,\varphi\rangle A\varphi_n$ And thus $\langle x,A\varphi\rangle = \sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N} \langle x, A\varphi_n\rangle \langle\varphi_n,\varphi\rangle$. Is there a flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: Ok, I see.  The identity $\langle \varphi_n, A\varphi\rangle = a_n\langle \varphi_n, \varphi\rangle$, which also appears in the beginning of the proof, has a minor leap in that you need to move the $A$ from right to left and use realness of $a_n$ to get it - so I think this should be mentioned and the last part expanded the way you did.

Comment: @JohnDoe I've added a brief statement at the end what kind of properties I've used in the proof (several times). Thanks again your your helpful comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the last part should be

$$\sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N} a_n \langle x,\varphi_n\rangle\langle \varphi_n,\varphi\rangle =\sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N}  \langle x,\varphi_n\rangle\langle \bar{a_n}\varphi_n,\varphi\rangle = \sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N}  \langle x,\varphi_n\rangle\langle a_n\varphi_n,\varphi\rangle = \sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N}  \langle x,\varphi_n\rangle\langle A\varphi_n,\varphi\rangle = \sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb N}  \langle x,\varphi_n\rangle\langle \varphi_n,A\varphi\rangle = \langle x,A\varphi\rangle$$

Using that the $a_n$ must be real and $A$ is self-adjoint.  Other than that looks ok to me.

[I'm assuming you're using the Physics convention of conjugate-linearity on the left which is consistent with your formulas.]

Comment: Yes, you're right! Thank you very much for your time and effort.